# How is this a git merge conflict?

Tags: git, merge

To my understanding, a merge conflict occurs when 2 users independently have updated snapshot A of a file and don't pull.  So whoever pushes second will have their push rejected due to a merge conflict.

I reenacted the above scenario and got a merge conflict when adding a comment that was not there before.  Here is conflict shown by my IDE:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    // my comment that I'm attempting to push
=======
>>>>>>> origin/coolFeature
```

Why is there a conflict here?  In this case the other user that pushed first did not push code for that specific line.

Comment: just remove the line around the comment and add/commit/push

Comment: there was no line around the comment; I simply added a comment above a function.  The IDE is showing a conflict exists between my comment and an empty string, which is the question I am asking.  I resolved the conflict, but I don't know why it is a conflict at all.

Comment: i meant the <<< HEAD and >> origin. The conflict is that you pulled the older version to your local version which had the comment - it goes by line number so in one version line x was empty, in your local version it had a comment

Comment: hmm previously in my experience git was smart enough to merge this automatically instead of rejecting the push due to a perceived conflict.  It would know, a line was added, merge and accept the push.

Comment: Is there some kind of eol (end of line characters) conflicts? What does `git config core.autocrlf` returns?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the coolfeature version deletes a line in the original -- the conflict isn't between your comment and an empty line, it's between your change to that line, producing that comment, and coolfeature's change to that line, deleting it.

Comment: I would suggest using [`diff3`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_conflicts_are_presented) conflict style, maybe that gives you a better impression how this conflict came into life.